# How to get the MPK using bitcoinj and how to generate the addresses using the MPK?

Tags: public-key, bitcoinj, private-key-import

I am trying to get the MPK of a wallet using bitcoinj. Can I get the DeterministicSeed, which is the seed of the wallet and get the MnemonicCode of 12 words. But I can't get the MPK. As I can make it using bitcoinj?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the way to do it:

```
    DeterministicKey extendedKey = wallet.getWatchingKey();
    String mpk = extendedKey.serializePubB58(wallet.getParams());
```